# Why there are two ways to create interceptors in spring boot project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, interceptor, handlerinterceptor

1. By extending the AbstractPhaseInterceptor. (org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor)
   https://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html
2. By implementing the HandlerInterceptor
   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_interceptor.htm

Which one is the best choice for Spring boot microservice creation?

Comment: (1) is the apache CXF stuff . nothing to do with spring-boot.....

Comment: you suggest that implementing HandlerInterceptor is the better way?

Comment: forget about (1) ,it is nothing to do with spring-boot. it is the stuff from another open source project called CXF , and you are asking the best choice for **spring-boot**